# Add UISlider to selected cell for row at index path

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

[image]

I would like to add a UISlider to the `Distance` cell and only the `Distance` cell and no others.

Currently all rows are created from the same cell.

How to add the slider just to the `Distance` row?

Something like cell for row - `if indexPath.row == 3`  or do I need to create a new complete cell?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 different cells with different identifiers. One for regular cells and another one for distance cell.

Return desired cell from `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method. This is the method where you check for `indexPath.row` and dequeue correct cell.

You can follow some tutorial ([like this](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/)) or check other questions about how to create custom cells and set their identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Couple options:

1. Add the slider in `cellForRowAt` based on the `indexPath` - kinda clunky and more work than necessary.
2. Add the `UISlider` to your prototype cell, and set its `.isHidden` property based on `indexPath` - no muss, no fuss, one additional line of code.
3. Create a second prototype cell, and load "cellTypeA" or "cellTypeB" based on `indexPath` - additional advantage is: if you decide you need a *3rd* type of cell, you've got the foundation in place.
4. Completely create the cell via code - sure, but lots of work, and I'm just listing it here to be thorough.

I'd recommend option 3.